# Can Jenkins send more than one email?

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After the build I want to trigger two e-mails.

The first one is an email to SharePoint server. SharePoint uploads its attachments. The subject of this mail must match a SharePoint folder for uploading.

The second one is a mail for team. So, it should have nice subject rather than folder name.

How can I make Jenkins send two emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no plugin that provides this functionality. You have two choices to accomplish this functionality. You could implement your own plugin. A good place to start would probably be the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

Alternatively, you could trigger the first email with the actual build and then have Jenkins trigger a separate, dummy build that sends the second email. This wouldn't be as elegant, but much easier as you wouldn't need to implement any functionality yourself. Depending on what exactly you want the emails to contain, you might have to transfer some data from the first to the second build (e.g. via a parameterized build).

Answer (score 0):

A cheap alternative is to create "shell script" Build steps, e.g.: (if on *nix platforms)

```
echo "Please Mr. SharePoint, would you be so kind to attach my file(s) ? 
      Thanks!" | mail -s "<folder name>" -a ${WORKSPACE}/target/artifacts/myfile sharepoint@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a new trigger and have the option to send a new email with new content to the recipient list.